# File permission in Linux, Allowing user upload in Amazon ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am making a web app that is hosted on amazon ec2. One of the page allows user to upload photo to the site.
MY script works on ordinary site, but not with ec2, so I suspect the problem is about connection or authorization.

Maybe ordinary web user do not have authorization to upload to the var/www/html/ directory? But how to enable them?

(specifically I think the following line is not working
move_uploaded_file)

I am using AMazon ec2 micro instance Linux AMI server. I am uploading via a form in a php file.

Comment: a bit more information will help everyone.  a)  what type of ec2 instance?  some *nix variant i'll assume.  webserver?  php?  help everyone help you...

Comment: Seems like you're running Apache2 with PHP. Generally I'd not want anyone to write to /var/www/html, but rather to /tmp with move_uploaded_file() and then to S3 from /tmp. If files are small, you can even create your little RAM drive as temp space.